# Flask Data is not stored to database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am Creating a Flask Application.Application is running perfectly on local server. There is no error but the data is not stored in the database. What am i Missing?

**1.routes.py**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
from models import db ,User
from forms import SignupForm

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:////Database.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db. init_app(app)

app.secret_key ='development_key'

@app.route('/' , methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form = SignupForm() #form object 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            return render_template('index.htm' , form=form)
        else:   
        #new user to be added to database   newuser = User(form.fname.data,form.lname.data,form.email.data,form.password.data)
            db.create_all()
            db.session.add(newuser)
            db.session.commit()
            return render_template('profile.htm')
    elif request.method == 'GET':                                                                   
        return render_template('index.htm',form=form)

@app.route('/aboutus')
def aboutus():
    return render_template('aboutus.htm')

@app.route('/profile')
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.htm')

@app.route('/contactus')
def contactus():
    return render_template('contactus.htm')
```

**2.app.py**

```
from routes import app
app.run(debug = True)
```

**3.forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm as Form
from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField,SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired,Email,Length

class SignupForm(Form):
    fname = StringField('First Name',validators=[DataRequired("Please Enter Your FirstName")])
    lname = StringField('Last Name',validators=[DataRequired("Please Enter Your LastName")])
    password = PasswordField('Password',validators=[DataRequired("Password Can't Be Empty"), Length(min=8,message="Password Must Be 8 character Long")])
    email = StringField('Email',validators=[DataRequired("Please Enter Your Email") , Email("Please Enter A Valid Email")]) 
    submit = SubmitField('Register')
```

**4.models.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__= "users"
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    lname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100),unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def __init__(self,fname,lname,email,password):
        self.fname=fname
        self.lname=lname
        self.email=email
        self.set_password(password)

    def set_password(self,password):
        self.password=generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self,password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password,password)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. The database wasn't being created. Try something like this instead to ensure your database file is in the proper place:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'Database.db')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use sqlite3 for production purpose and rather use postgresql because sqlite3 is good for local machine stuff and does not work well on the online servers as it is also does not works well on the heroku hosting platform where the database gets reset at least once in every 24 hours for which you can even check the following link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3  though you did not mentioned using heroku but I am still suggesting this because heroku is very common hosting place.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP, as it seems that the data isn't being stored locally either.